# How to solve Script timeout passed error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, script

Live site DB import into localhost wamp server, its return

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
>   the same file and import will resume.

Error : [image]

How can i solve this error?

```
My DB Size : 1.4GB
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because importing large DB dumps into phpMyAdmin is not specific to Magento

Answer (score 1):

Try to import via CLI. Use this command:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: also tried, not working

Comment: my db size 1.4 gb

Comment: Well, in that case, try to use this method: https://cmanios.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/import-a-large-sql-dump-file-to-a-mysql-database-from-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql database is very big,
you might want to compress the output of mysqldump. Just use the mysql backup command below and pipe the output to gzip, then you will get the output as gzip file.

> $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] | gzip -9 >
>   [backupfile.sql.gz]

take backup and restore

> gunzip < output.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p password database

Comment: not working ...  i tried already

Comment: compress using command line restore

Comment: actually, i compressed my DB as a name.sql.dz still not successfully import.

Comment: Hw can i  run this, could you pls sent screen shots  :: gunzip < output.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p password database